# глюк с background-attachment

Tags: css, webkit

Есть [сайт](http://galss.net/),  там четыре картинки в середнине сайта.

На браузерах *webkit* не срабатывает или глючит `background-attachment`.

Может, подскажете, в чем дело?

Comment: Там до хрена четырёх картинок вряд. И не понятно, что подразумевается под словом "глючит"? Ванги на Ren-TV. :)

Comment: там шесть центральных картинок картинок на весь экран. Четыре приатачены background-attachment при скроле любым вебкит браузером глюк вываливается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Баги Хрома + неправильная вёрстка. Шаги решения:

- Из body убрать **-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;** — из-за
  него жутко глючит **background-attachment: fixed;**
- Добавить в класс **.cd-fixed-background** свойство **overflow:
  hidden;**
- Убрать из класса **.cd-fixed-background** свойство **position:
  relative;**
- Изменить в классе **.opacity** свойство **position: absolute;** на **position:
  relative;**

*P.S.* *Проверьте потом работоспособность в FF и других, ибо я тестил напрямую через dev-tools.*

Comment: А вы не можете подсказать где верстка не правильная. Мне ведь больше для того что бы понять в чем проблема или ссылку дать на статью

Comment: А я описал это в стилях. :) Не использовать **-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;** с **background-attachment: fixed;** и не использовать **position: relative;** на том элементе, где **background-attachment: fixed;** В Хроме это помогает.